# Hibernate Jar conflicts with grails 2.0.3

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have a grails(2.0.3) application that has a jar dependency on another project which uses hibernate jars, namely:

**`org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.0.Final`**

and

**`org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.1.0.Final`**

When I run that part of code which uses these jars it encounters an exception :-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

It occurs like a jar conflict problem with the hibernate version that grails is using(I am not sure). How can I resolve this issue.

(It would be difficult to switch the hibernate version of the dependent project. So can I resolve this without going for that option.)

Comment: Did you try to exclude this subdependency?

Comment: If i mention the dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy it gives me an exception in the application startup  :   context.GrailsContextLoader Error executing bootstraps: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor
 at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:736)
 at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:569)

Comment: and the effect is the very same as my first case if i avoid the transitive dependency for the jars like this in BuildConfig:-         runtime "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.1.0.Final" {
    transitive = false
   }

Comment: So, you have a situation when you need both (and confilcting) versions of hibernate? I'm not sure that there is exists a quick way to fix. Probably you can try to make your own classloader, but I can't help there, sorry

Comment: Yes, thats the scenario where i am stuck at. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue finally by using hibernate jars with version 3.6 for the dependent application. Grails seems to be using this version. This removed the conflict issues. :-)